# Unable to add RSS Feed to PHP website

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

I am new to Programming and i don't know about RSS feed so, after some google search finally i created a code for Rss feed but its saying syntax error, so, plese help me to correct the issue.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
include("lib/config.php");
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * From job_jobs where job_status=0 order by jid DESC limit 0, 15");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'?>
 <rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
  <title>Mynextmove.biz Jobs</title>
  <description>Active jobs</description>
  <link>http://mynextmove.biz</link>

  <?php
   while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  ?>
   <item>
    <title><?php echo $row['job_title'];?></title>
    <description><?php echo $row['job_description'];?></description>
    <link>http://mynextmove.biz/job_apply.php?jid=<?php echo $row['jid'];?></link>
    <pubdate><?php echo $row['date_time']; ?></pubdate>
   </item>
   <?php
   }?>
  </channel>
  </rss>
 <?php
 }?>
```

Update:
Now i got error like this on webpage

"This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 7: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

And in Rss validator its showing error as

"This feed does not validate.

line 2, column 1: XML parsing error: :2:1: XML or text declaration not at start of entity [help]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <rss version="2.0">
```

^
In addition, interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendation.

Your feed appears to be encoded as "utf-8", but your server is reporting "US-ASCII""

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to attach the correct error. I visited website on which you took the screenshot and got the error message:

> error on line 2 at column 7: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

This error shows up when - as it states - there are characters before `<?xml` declaration. Look in your code. Is there ***any*** character before `<?php`? If so, remove them. If you `echo` anything before echoing `<?xml`, delete these echos too.

Comment: Thank you. Now updated as you suggested but still getting the error please check my updated post for Error and i didn't echo any thing before <?xml

Comment: Can you show me content of `lib/config.php`? Of course change the credentials

Comment: <?php
 $db_host="localhost";
 $db_username="XXXXXX";
 $db_pwd="XXXXXX";
 $db_name="XXXXXXX"; 
 $conn= @mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pwd); 
 $db = @mysql_select_db($db_name,$conn);
 ?>

Comment: do you have ***ANY*** character before `<?php` or after `?>`? It would be nic if you completely removed `?>` from this file